# What's the correct algorithm to filter accumulating string concatenations?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, filtering-problem

I have a function that is receiving messages with the following pattern:

[image: Example of accumulating strings]

(In this picture, "string" and "message" are synonymous.)

I'm only interested in the largest messages, such as these:

[image: Largest filtered accumulated strings]

over a particular window.

Is there an algorithm that can appropriately filter the messages in the desired manner over a specified window?

Comment: The examples do *not* show how to handle `m1, m1´` and, later on, `m1, m1´´` ("forks"). Is the *CorrelationId* part of the messages received?

Comment: `m1, m1'` would be dropped/removed. `m1, m1''` is not a valid case. It would just be `m1, m1'`. The correlationId can be included in each message, or it can be outside each message in an envelope that would be discarded prior to the filtering algorithm. 
Does that answer the question?

Comment: The statements about example messages `m1` to `m1, m1''` escape me. (When `m1, m1''` is not valid after `m1, m1'`, shouldn't `m1, m1''` be dropped? How come that after dropping `m1, m1'` `It would just be m1, m1'`?) The alternatives given for *CorrelationId * answer the explicit question in my comment above. Please edit additional information you think helpful for answering your question into the question body, if any.

Comment: From how I currently read the question: put the messages in a [prefix tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Answer (score 1):

Store them in a heap or priority queue, keyed on the size of the message.  This way, if you want the $k$ largest messages, you can keep track of that as each message arrives.  This will require $O(k)$ space to keep track of the $k$ largest messages at each step, and $O(\log k)$ time per message that arrives, so it should be pretty efficient.